# separate an array into two halves

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I like to split an array into first half and its second half. I tried following code, but it does not work:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
B = A[:len(A)/2]
C = A[len(A)/2:]
```

The error message says:

```
TypeError: slice indices must be integers or None or have an __index__ method
```

Supposedly, I should get

```
B = [0,1,2]

C = [3,4,5]
```

I am wondering how I should do it? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are doing float-math - use integer division:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
B = A[:len(A)//2]
C = A[len(A)//2:]

print(A,B,C)
```

Output:

```
([1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6], [1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6])
```

Have a look at the operators here:  [numeric-types-int-float-complex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=floor%20division#numeric-types-int-float-complex)

Answer (score 3):

try this

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
half = len(A)//2
B = A[:half]
C = A[half:]
```

Comment: Since you're using the half of the list twice it's always a good practice to save the result of the midway calc in a variable. It's way faster. Maybe this part of the code will be called thousands of times  inside a function inside a loop. But if this code will run only once or fewer times you can use the expression inside the list separator

Answer (score 2):

The error message states that you should be using integers. Your division by 2 currently results in a float. You can cast it into an integer using `int()`:

```
A = [1,2,3,4,5,6]
B = A[:int(len(A)/2)]
C = A[int(len(A)/2):]

print(B)
print(C)
```

Out:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[4, 5, 6]
```

Comment: cast to int ? use `//`

Comment: @PatrickArtner Sure, I suppose thats more pythonic. To me the `int()` is a bit more explicit and clear, but I can see many people disagreeing with that. This answer will still work in cases where the `2` is provided externally (and might be `2.0`) instead of as a magic number. This will also work for a multiplication by `0.5` instead of division by `2`.